# White border between flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I create a container div, then I create a top and bottom div, in the bottom I create 2 more divs, to put separeted items, but, in the middle of them it's a border that a didn't put there, I tried the same code only with divs (whitout text) to see, and it didn't has the border in the middle of them, so, anyone knows why?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-text">
      <h1>Join our community</h1>

      <h3>30-day, hassle-free money back guarantee</h3>

      <p>Gain access to our full library of tutorials along with expert code reviews. Perfect for any developers who are serious about honing their skills.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-text">
      <div class="month-sub">
        <h3 class="month-sub-title">Monthly Subscription</h3>

        <p class="p-dollar"><span class="dollar">&dollar;29</span> per month</p>

        <p>Full access for less than &dollar;1 a day</p>

        <button class="btn-sign">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
      <div class="why-us">
        <h3 class="why-us-title">Why Us</h3>

        <ul class="specs">
          <li>Tutorials by industry experts</li>
          <li>Peer &amp; expert code review</li>
          <li>Coding exercises</li>
          <li>Access to our GitHub repos</li>
          <li>Community forum</li>
          <li>Flashcard decks</li>
          <li>New videos every week</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


.container{
    width: 44%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.top-text{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 35px;
    color: var(--cyan);
}

.bottom-text{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.month-sub{
    width: 50%;
    padding: 35px;
    background-color: var(--cyan);
}

.why-us{
    width: 50%;
    padding: 35px;
    background-color: var(--grayishBlue); 
}
```

**The border**

[image: The border]

**The div I create with the same things, but didn't have the border**

[image: The div I create with the same things, but didn't have the border]

Comment: Welcome to SO. can you add html code to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: What about adding a margin between them?

Comment: With images we can impossibly tell u what the issue is, show us the HTML code for both. What u could do so far is inspect the div below with the dev tool in google chrome or firefox, and then precisely examine the css and the HTML to check if there is code like a white border or similar u didn't expect.

Comment: My guess is that this is antialiasing caused by sub-pixel calcuations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it can be due to wrong use of flexbox. If you use display: flex; you shoul use flex: 0 1 50%; in child to benefit from it.

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
}
.child{
    //this 
    flex: 0 1 50$; 
    //is equivalent of this
    flex-grow: 0
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

My second guess it's box-sizing or some styles are being inherited...

Anyway maybe it'll help you
https://codepen.io/jerrykck/pen/eYZbpGN